# I am getting "No primary or single unique constructor found " Exception while trying to HttpServletRequest request submission in Postman

Tags: java, servlets, postman, spring-restcontroller

I would like to simulate a request submission using Postman. I am not sure what to put in Postman for my request if I have a HttpServletRequest in input to my method.

This is my Controller:

```
    @RestController
    public class MyController {
    
        @PostMapping(path = "/test")
        public ResponseEntity<String> test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    
            final String host=request.getRemoteAddr();
            final String key = request.getParameter("key");
            final String application = request.getParameter("nomeApp");
...

    }
```

My understanding is that when a HttpServletRequest object is in input to a method in Rest Controller class, I don't have to pass parameters because in someway the request is processed itself.

My Postman
[image]
[image]

This is my exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:266) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
```

These are the dependencies used in my POM

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <!-- Excluded commons-io because of CVE-2021-29425 -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Remember that JSON doesn't support comments.

Comment: I've removed the comments but still the same problem: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Comment: Your URL should be localhost:8080/upload/test

Comment: I just changed it before testing. Same issue with localhost:8080/upload/test.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue before.

I'm upgrading the spring from 2.7.x to 3.0.4

the problem is because the `HttpServletRequest` that I used is from `javax.servlet.http`

change it to `jakarta.servlet.http`

Comment: Yep ^^ that was the reason for me too. Silly right?

Answer (score 1):

Like someone said in one of the above comments, changing to ServerHttpRequest fixed it for me

```
package dev.logickoder.headerparser

import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController


@RestController
object HeaderParserController {

  @GetMapping("/api/whoami")
  fun whoAmI(request: ServerHttpRequest): Map<String, String?> {
    return mapOf(
      "ipaddress" to request.remoteAddress?.toString(),
      "language" to request.headers["accept-language"]?.firstOrNull(),
      "software" to request.headers["user-agent"]?.firstOrNull(),
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ServerHttpRequest instead of HttpServletRequest. ServerHttpRequest is the implementation class of HttpServletRequest.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(ServerHttpRequest request) {

        final String host=request.getRemoteAddr();
        final String key = request.getParameter("key");
        final String application = request.getParameter("nomeApp");
```

...

```
}
```

Comment: I still get the same exception : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest"

Comment: can you post come more code of the imports used?

Comment: To be honest I was trying to test with postman the apache file upload from baeldung. https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-web-modules/spring-rest-simple/src/main/java/com/baeldung/apachefileupload/UploadController.java

Comment: he uses HttpServletRequest  in the input of his rest/post method but I don't know how to use postman to test it. @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleUpload(HttpServletRequest request) {

Comment: I think you must have used wrong imports for httpservlet can u check it once

Comment: I used the one from spring: import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;

Comment: You've imported the wrong class:

org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest is for Spring MVC.......
org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest is for Spring WebFlux

Comment: Use this import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest

Comment: unfortunately, it's the same exception. Please check the original example I am trying to follow. He uses  HttpServletRequest as an input for POST request. I don't know what to put in Postman. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-apache-file-upload

Comment: which import you have used for httpservletrequest?

Comment: import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

Comment: still same exception coming?

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work with Spring boot 3+. When I downgrade to Spring boot 2, it worked and my controller get the request.